# Just-in-time debugger throwing errors during compile

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using VS 2008. I have a C# application.

When I try to build/run the project it opens the JUST IN TIME debugger for some reason disabling me from stepping through my code where the exception occurred.

How can I get rid of this JUST IN TIME prompt?

I did go to tools=>options-->debugging and disabled JUST IN TIME and now it is giving me an error message:

an unhandled win32 exception occurred in projectname. just in time debugging this exception failed with the following error...basically i guess it's trying to open just in time

How do I get normal compiler debugging capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following MSDN article: [Just-In-Time Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx). It sounds like in your case, you might want to make sure you have registry keys for JIT deleted.

Also, the following seems to be applicable in your case:

> An unhandled win32 exception occurred in . Just-In-Time
>   debugging this exception failed with the following error: The logged
>   in user did not have access to debug the crashing application.
>
> This message indicates that Just-In-Time debugging failed because you
>   do not have proper access permissions. For information on the required
>   permissions, see [Obsolete] Remote Debugging Permissions.